# Obter id mais elevado e menos elevado com status = 1

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho uma tabela no banco de dados com várias linhas,

Eu queria obter o id mais elevado, que tenha status = 1, como poderei fazer isso com o php? O id é uma coluna da tabela e o status é outra.

Depois, também quero saber como pego o menos elevado.

```
<?php

$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "vertrigo", "csgodouble");


$contador = 0;



    $verifica = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT MAX(id) FROM apostas WHERE status = 1 ");
$sql = mysqli_fetch_array($verifica);



echo $sql["numero_sorteado"];



?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amigo apenas com php não é possível, tem que utilizar o mysql .
Bom, mas acredito que isso ja deve estar utilizando.
Faça o seguinte : no select coloca o where status = 1 e adicione uma clausula no select order by id desc , essa clausula ira listar as linhas com id do maior para o menor ( decrescente ) , faça um for, receba o primeiro id e de um break.
Entendeu ? 
Deu certo ? 
Select =

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE status = 1 ORDER BY id DESC
```

E para pegar do menor pro maior:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE status = 1 ORDER BY id ASC
```

Comment: Pode dar uma resposta com o codigo por favor?

Comment: @Gonçalo  poste seu select e como percorre ele , pois estou pelo celular...

Comment: A partir daqui consigo obter o id mais elevado com status = 1?

Comment: S , pois o order by id desc ordena as linhas de id em decrescente, e o where pega apenas id com o status 1

Comment: Não consegui com o seu codigo.

Comment: Consegui agora.

Comment: Q ue bom @Gonçalo ...

Comment: @AugustoFurlan adaptei sua resposta, pois editei a pergunta com uma dúvida a mais do autor, tudo bem? Só acrescentei a opção inversa.

Answer (score 2):

Você não precisa atribuir isto ao php, pois daria um trabalho desnecessário.

Para pegar somente o numero_sorteado com o id mais elevado basta executar o sql utilizando o `MAX()`, desta forma:

```
SELECT numero_sorteado, MAX(id) FROM apostas WHERE status = 1
```

Para pegar o menor:

```
SELECT numero_sorteado, MIN(id) FROM apostas WHERE status = 1
```

Comment: Boa tarde, sim seria isso mas o código está a dar erro.

Comment: Qual o erro que está retornando @Gonçalo ?

Comment: @Gonçalo o código da resposta me parece apropriado e responder o problema, se não funciona, você deve adicionar como está o seu cógido na pergunta, sem ele, não tem como advinhar a causa do problema.

Comment: Adicionei o código completo o erro que me dá é: "Undefined index: numero_sorteado" pois quero o * e isso não tem.

Comment: @Gonçalo o erro ocorre porque só vem a coluna id, você tem que declarar todas as colunas que quer retornar no select, algo assim: `select numero_sorteado, max(id) from apostas where status = 1`

Comment: Ele não deixou muito claro na pergunta, mas parece que id e numero_sorteado são colunas diferentes, assim como status.

Comment: verdade @DiegoF... Gonçalo, podes deixar mais claro caso ainda não dê certo com o que o Diego sugeriu?

Comment: Sim, são colunas diferentes.

Comment: @Gonçalo então teste o código da forma que sugeri que irá funcionar.

Comment: Não funcionou o código mostra apenas o 1º id da tabela.

Comment: @InácioRégis adaptei sua resposta, pois editei a pergunta com uma dúvida a mais do autor, tudo bem? Só acrescentei a opção inversa.