# Obter id menor com status = 1

Tags: php

Recentemente abri uma pergunta no stack overflow, de como faria para obter o maior id com um select e com status = 1.

Link da Pergunta: [Obter id mais elevado e menos elevado com status = 1](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/116752/obter-id-mais-elevado-com-status-1)

Bom, agora a minha dúvida é contrária, como faço para obter o menor id com status = 1.

Obrigado.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM table WHERE status = 1 ORDER BY id ASC`

Comment: Obrigado Diego!

Comment: Gonçalo, é a mesmíssima lógica da outra resposta. Na primeira, só troca o `DESC` (descending) por `ASC` (ascending). Na segunda, `MAX( )` da resposta de lá pega o maior, no lugar dele você usa o `MIN( )` pra pegar o menor. `AVG( )` é pra pegar a média, e assim vai. Todas perguntas são bem-vindas, mas se você também der uma lidinha na documentação, fica mais facil até pra você saber onde achar alguma coisa na hora que precisa. Se mesmo assim não conseguir resolver, deixe um comentário.

Comment: Editei a sua outra pergunta e as respostas, pra facilitar. Agora esta com as duas dúvidas respondidas no mesmo lugar, e com exemplos.

Comment: Na verdade bastava pergunta ao autor da antiga pergunta "para que serve o DESC", embora isso já tenha sido explicado. Acho que por padrão a ordem do MySQL é ASC, portanto removendo o DESC iria mostrar a ordem que deseja, sem nem a necessidade de acrescentar o ASC. Acho que tentativa e erro pode ser um bom caminho, ao menos para aprender o que faz cada item dali. Ir "destruindo" o código aprende, ao menos alguma coisa, o que cada coisa faz. A documentação terá utilidade (e mais sentido) depois que souber ao mais ou menos o que cada coisa faz, ou seja cada coisa destruída faz.